# Check both GET and SESSION for a variable

Tags: php, session, get, session-variables

I am trying to figure out why my from isn't retaining variables. I have been testing this all afternoon with no luck. The code seems to be correct, but I am guessing that something must be off.

I will explain my thought process when I wrote the code and then I will copy it below. Please correct me if I am coding/thinking incorrectly.

1. I get $asset and $serial from the url. Only one or the other will be there.
2. I check if the session has been started
3. If $asset/$serial is not blank (meaning something was found in step 1) I put $asset/$serial into the session.
4. If either $asset or $serial are in the session, I echo them to their respective text boxes.

The problem I keep running into is that the session only seems to be holding whatever variable is currentaly in the url. I need them to be saved in the session because the zxing barcode scanner only can send one variable at a time back.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?
//Get Asset/serial tags
$asset = $_GET['asset'];
$serial = $_GET['serial'];
if(isset($_SESSION)){
    //session not started
    session_start();
}
if($asset!=""){
    $_SESSION["asset"]=$asset;
} elseif($serial!=""){
    $_SESSION["serial"]=$serial;
}  

echo'
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="addComputer.php" name="newComputerForm">
      <label for="asset">Asset Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="asset" id="asset" value="'.$_SESSION["asset"].'">
      <a href="zxing://scan/?ret=http://example.com/jquerytest.php?asset=%7BCODE%7D">Scan an Asset</a>
      <label for="serial">Serial Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="serial" id="serial" value="'.$_SESSION["serial"].'">
      <a href="zxing://scan/?ret=http://example.com/jquerytest.php?serial=%7BCODE%7D">Scan a Serial</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>';
```

Comment: session_start should NOT be inside the condition it should always  be *before any output*

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Is there a way I could have written it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are validating your data with non strict operands. If you have no asset in the URL your $asset would be null. using the code:

```
//validates true in this scenario.
if($asset!=""){
    $_SESSION["asset"]=$asset; // $_SESSION["asset"] contains null.
}
```

Instead of != use !== to check for empty string. Also assign $asset with isset:

```
//Get Asset/serial tags
$asset = isset($_GET['asset']) ? $_GET['asset'] : null;
$serial = isset($_GET['serial']) ? $_GET['serial'] : null;

//check session started. using the comment of Yair.R
if(session_id() == ''){
    //session not started
    session_start();session_id()
}
if($asset !== null){
    $_SESSION["asset"]=$asset;
} elseif($serial !== null){
    $_SESSION["serial"]=$serial;
}
```

For more info on strict operands:  [PHP: Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the condition like this:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

also, maybe your $_GET vars are undefined so always check them:

```
$asset = isset($_GET['asset'])? $_GET['asset'] : '';
```